# Solidity Type Error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm getting this strange error:

```
TypeError: Type function (uint256) pure returns (uint256[] memory) is 
not implicitly convertible to expected type uint[256] memory.
```

The error appears on *each* of the first 3 lines of code in my `getBoughtImages()` function. So every one of my 3 variables is "guilty" of whatever this is.

Not really sure what's going on - here's the full code:

```
struct Img {
    uint IDNumber;
    string color;
    address ownerAddress;
}


Img[] public imgsBoughtArray;



function getBoughtImages() public view returns (uint256[] memory imgsIDs, string[] memory imgsColors, address[] memory ownerIds) {
    uint[] memory boughtImgsIdsArray = new uint[];
    string[] memory imgsColorsArray = new string[];
    address[] memory ownersAddressesArray =  new address[];

    for (uint i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        boughtImgsIdsArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].IDNumber);
        imgsColorsArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].color);
        ownersAddressesArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].ownerAddress);
    }
    return (boughtImgsIdsArray, imgsColorsArray, ownersAddressesArray);
}
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: usually the code starts with pragma... what is that struct doing there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract d {
    struct Img {
        uint IDNumber;
        string color;
        address ownerAddress;
    }

    Img[] public imgsBoughtArray;

    function getBoughtImages() public returns (uint256[] memory imgsIDs, string[] memory imgsColors, address[] memory ownerIds) {
        uint[] memory boughtImgsIdsArray = new uint[](10);
        string[] memory imgsColorsArray = new string[](10);
        address[] memory ownersAddressesArray =  new address[](10);

        for (uint i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            boughtImgsIdsArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].IDNumber);
            imgsColorsArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].color);
            ownersAddressesArray[i] = (imgsBoughtArray[i].ownerAddress);
        }
        return (boughtImgsIdsArray, imgsColorsArray, ownersAddressesArray);
    }
}
```